# Оптимизация php и mysql

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

И опять вопросы по работе с mysql и php:

1) Есть два запроса:

```
mysql_query('select * from `table` where `id`='.$id.' and `user_id`='.$_SESSION['id']);
mysql_query('select * from `table` where `id`='.$id.' and `user_id`='.$_SESSION['id'].'limit 0, 1');
```

Первичный ключ - id. Имеет ли смысл писать limit 0, 1 в конце запроса или это не ускорит запрос?

2) В случае уже полученных данных:

```
$ar = array();
$res = mysql_query('select * from `table` where `id`<30');
while($ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){}
```

Что лучше использовать: `mysql_num_rows($res)` или `sizeof($ar)` ?

3) Зачем нужен `mysql_fetch_array`, если есть `mysql_fetch_assoc` и `mysql_fetch_row`? По идее, эти две функции по отдельности работают быстрее?

4) При организации, допустим, блогов, разумно ли вынести посты блогов в отдельные файлы, а комментарии оставить в БД? Просто тогда получается, что при выводе последних блогов одновременно будет вестись работа как с БД, так и с файлами, что мне не нравится. Тем более, что анонс все равно придется писать в БД.

5) Определение глобальных переменных в функции - довольно медленная вещь. Можно ли ускорить работу функции, загнав ссылки на нужные переменные в массив и определив в функции глобальным только новый массив? То есть, было:

```
function f() {
    global $ar1, $ar2, $ar3;
}
```

Стало:

```
$all = array('ar1' => &$ar1, 'ar2' => &$ar2, 'ar3' => &$ar3);
function f() {
    global $all;
    $ar1 = $all['ar1'];
}
```

Если целесообразность некоторых вопросов у вас вызвала недоумение, считайте, что я любитель экономить на спичках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Имеет смысл сделать так:

```
mysql_query('select * from `table` where `id`='.$_SESSION['id'].' limit 0,1');
```

Только исключите в запросах *, тогда будет экономия уже не на спичках :)

2) Согласен с [[[[@mozzart](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)

3) mysql_fetch_array работает быстрее, чем assoc, т.к. добавляет только индексы в массив.

4) Согласен с [[[[@mozzart](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)](/users/2018/mozzart)

5) Скорее вот так быстрее:

```
function (&$ar1, &$ar2, &$ar3) {
...
}
```

Пример:

```
class Api {

    private $db;

    public function test() { // Этой функции Вы собирались передать get и post

        $this->db; // объект бд

    }

}
```

или так:

```
class Api extends DB {

    public function test() {
        $this->query();
    }

}
class DB {

    public function query() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Есть только пара вопросов:  
3) _array добавляет и индексы, и названия. Индексы добавляет _row. В принципе, у _array есть второй параметр, указывающий, что добавлять к массиву. Результат дублирует действие _assoc или _row.  
5) А что делать, если есть несколько т.н. переменных окружения, которые не удобно передавать в функцию, но удобнее объявить глобальными?

Comment: 3) Торможу по ночам :) У меня своя функция, использую mysql_* функции только 1 раз в за весь проект.
5) Я не особо понимаю для чего это нужно... Без global можно всегда обойтись, было бы желание. Приведите нормальный пример :)

Comment: Элементарно: создаем массивы $get и $post из обработанных значений $_GET и $_POST. Есть несколько классов, использующих в большинстве методов эти массивы. Передавать $get и $post в качестве параметров не очень удобно. Плюс, еще часто фигурирует $db - объект класса БД. Как это лучше переписать?

Comment: Ну в таком случае - я вообще не вижу смысла что-то передавать. $_GET и $_POST - и так супер глобальные массивы, смысл искать в них что-то, а потом передавать часть... У меня тоже есть объект с db, но я использую расширение классов для этого. Ниже привел пример.

Comment: Как я уже писал выше, $get и $post содержат уже обработанные значения $_GET и $_POST, что позволяет работать с ними без опасения за БД.

Comment: Тогда запиши их в $_POST и $_GET обратно :) Что-то типа того:
<pre>
$_GET = func($_GET);
$_POST = func($_POST);
$_REQUEST = func($_REQUEST);
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

1) Смысл есть

2) Если нужно просто получить количество записей, то логичнее и оптимизированней использовать mysql_num_rows, если все записи получены в массив, то тогда конечно - sizeof

3) Не проверял...

4) Если хранение файлов подразумевает организацию кэширование, то тогда да. Грубо говоря, работа с файлами происходит намного быстрее чем с БД

5) Первый вариант быстрее

Comment: Спасибо. Лаконично, но не очень понятно.